# 100st derivative $(\sinh(x)*\cosh(x))^2$ at point $x=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

$$\frac{\mathrm d^{100}}{\mathrm dx^{100}}(\sinh(x)*\cosh(x))^2$$
Without Taylor
I try this :$\sinh(x)'=\cosh(x)'$ but that didn't help in using General Leibniz rule.

Comment: Note that the first derivative is $\sinh(4x)/2$, this should be feasible to "differentiate by induction"

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$(\sinh(x)\cosh(x))^2 = \frac1{16}(e^{4x}+e^{-4x}) - \frac18.$$

Answer (score 0):

May be, write $$\sinh(x)\cosh(x)=\frac 12 \sinh(2x)$$ So $$\sinh^2(x)\cosh^2(x)=\frac 14 \sinh^2(2x)=\frac 14 \frac {\cosh(4x)-1}2=\frac 18 \cosh(4x)-\frac 18 $$ which gives you something looking nicer (I hope).